# System.ObjectDisposedException используя Using

Tags: c#

Интересная ситуация, кто объяснит такой феномен, используя Using для реализации Idisposable

```
private string GetWhoIs(string whoisServer, string ipAddr)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilderResult = new StringBuilder();            
    using (TcpClient tcpClinetWhois = new TcpClient(whoisServer, 80))
    {
        using (NetworkStream networkStreamWhois = tcpClinetWhois.GetStream())
        {
            using (BufferedStream bufferedStreamWhois = new BufferedStream(networkStreamWhois))
            {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(bufferedStreamWhois))
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(ipAddr);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    using (StreamReader streamReaderReceive = new StreamReader(bufferedStreamWhois))
                    {
                        while (!streamReaderReceive.EndOfStream)
                            stringBuilderResult.AppendLine(streamReaderReceive.ReadLine());
                    }
              **}**
            }
        }
    }

    return stringBuilderResult.ToString();
}
```

На выделенной строке происходит вызов исключения. На картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, что и как происходит закрытие потока. Что-то не то со Streamreader мое предположение. Спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Конструкторы `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` с одним параметром выставляют приватное свойство `LeaveOpen` в `false`. Это значит, что когда вы диспозите их экземпляры, то они диспозят и внутренний поток.

Здесь бы не было проблемы, так как по канонам Microsoft все `IDisposable` должны поддерживать вызов `Dispose()` множество раз, и при этом не приводить к ошибке. А дело в том, что `StreamWriter` во время `Dispose()` пытается вызвать `Flush()` на потоке. Но этот поток уже закрыл `StreamReader`, и вы получаете ошибку.

Как уже указали в другом ответе, вы можете использовать другой конструктор:

```
new StreamReader(bufferedStreamWhois, true, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, leaveOpen: true);
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

> To help ensure that resources are always cleaned up appropriately, a
>   Dispose method should be callable multiple times without throwing an
>   exception.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло - только в параметре true в последнем

Comment: @RomanIeromenko да, всё верно, ошибочка была

Answer (score 2):

Поток закрывает reader/writer. 
Можно оставить его открытым после выхода из using, для этого в конструкторе установить leaveOpen в true
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Boolean_System_Int32_System_Boolean_

Answer (score 1):

Вы действительно хотели создать читатель и писатель с одним и тем же потоком `bufferedStreamWhois`?

Исключение о закрытом потоке относится к `bufferedStreamWhois`. Читатель в своем `Dispose` закрывает `bufferedStreamWhois`, а потом то же самое делает писатель.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_IO_Stream_

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_

Comment: Ну вообще-то по канонам `Dispose` можно вызывать не один раз, и такие вызовы не должны приводить к исключениям.

Comment: @Zergatul https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2202-do-not-dispose-objects-multiple-times?view=vs-2017

Comment: Это просто хорошая практика для пользовательского кода, но библиотечные классы должны поддерживать такое.

Comment: Добавил в своем ответе цитату про многоразовый вызов Dispose